# PHP count values in multidimensional-array where key and value equals

Tags: php, function, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a dashboard with some information like how many users are male or female. I'm storing profile information already in one multidimensional-array called 'users'. To count the total male/female users I want to use a function with multiple arguments (the array, key and value.

I tried the following code:

```
  <?
    function countArray($array, $key, $value) {
      $cnt = count(array_filter($array,function($element) {
        return $element[$key]== $value;
      }));
      echo $cnt;
    }

    countArray($users, 'gender', '1');
  ?>
```

This results in Undefined variable: key/values. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that anonymous functions in PHP do not have access to variables outside of their own scope. As such, the `array_filter()` callback function you've provided has no knowledge of `$key` or `$value`, and so they're undefined variables within that function scope. To fix this, you must explicitly pass the external variables into the function scope using the `use` keyword, like `function() use ($external_variable) {}`.

In your case, the solution would look something like this:

```
<?
    function countArray($array, $key, $value) {
      $cnt = count(array_filter($array,function($element) use ($key, $value) {
        return $element[$key]== $value;
      }));
      echo $cnt;
    }

    countArray($users, 'gender', '1');
?>
```

If you're using PHP 7.4 or above, you can also just use an arrow function to allow the external scope to become part of the function scope implicitly:

```
<?
    function countArray($array, $key, $value) {
      $cnt = count(array_filter($array,fn($element) => $element[$key]== $value ));
      echo $cnt;
    }

    countArray($users, 'gender', '1');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function($element) use ($key, $value) {
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.